# Point Webflow site to example.com/webflow-site

Tags: redirect, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, google-domains

I'm using google domains to host my frontend web application at example.com. I also have marketing pages that are built on webflow.com that I'd like to seamlessly integrate with the example.com.

I'd like to route my webflow website to example.com/webflow-site. All of its pages will look like example.com/weflow-site/page-1. My frontend app's pages will look like example.com/page.

Currently, the best I can do is example.com and webflow-site.example.com.

Any help here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up reverse proxy on the domain, which proxies requests to the webflow package. How to do it depends on the web server software you run on your own domain.